# JSON API Missing Field

Tags: php, json, wordpress, rest, api

I can grab the image_gallery from my site by using the wp-json, but not JSON API. I'm using a template but it is based on JSON API. The thing is, it is not grabbing the image_gallery like wp-json does. I need help.

http://www.brunei.events/wp-json/tevolution/v2/city/brunei/post/type/event

```
image_gallery   
0   "http://www.brunei.events/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/YEPCharityPoster1513050372.png"
```

How can I achieve this using JSON API plugin? Where do I need to add / change the code?

Comment: Please give a link to the JSON API plugin you are using.

Comment: @designtocode Here is the link to the plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/json-api/